# Performance issue in merge statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, merge-statement

I have a merge statement like below

```
    MERGE DESTINATION AS DST
 USING ( SELECT <Some_Columns> FROM TABLEA WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN TableB .....

       ) AS SRC
   ON(
     <some conditions>
   )

 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET column1 = src.column1
              ...............
              ,Modified_By = @PackageName
              ,Modified_Date = GETDATE() 

 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 

    INSERT (<Some_Columns>)
    VALUES(<Some_Columns>)

         OUTPUT        
                  $action, inserted.key'inserted'
                   INTO @tableVar
                ;
```

For the first set of records (around 300,000) it is working perfectly and executing in just 30 seconds.
But for the second set of records (around 300,000) it is taking more than an hour.

Two days back I have loaded 50 sets like that and the same query was working lightning fast, but from today it is damn slow. I have no idea what is going wrong.

Note: Query

> SELECT  FROM TABLEA WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN TableB .....

is taking 20 seconds in all scenerios.

Comment: Did you check for `blocking_session_id` or `wait_type_desc` in `sys.dm_exec_requests`? Really hard for anyone here to guess why it's taking a long time.

Comment: Also you might want to be careful about `MERGE` - I don't want to sound like Chicken Little, but I highlight TWELVE yet-to-be-resolved bugs at the bottom of this post: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug

Comment: @AaronBertrand +1 for mentioning the link. Now I believe I should change my query instead of digging up this issue. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the `MERGE` syntax is nicer, and it *seems* to promise better atomicity and no race conditions ([but doesn't, unless you add `HOLDLOCK`, as this Dan Guzman post demonstrates](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)), I still feel like it is better to hang onto the old-style, separate insert/update methodology. The primary reason is not that the syntax is hard to learn (which it is), or that it is difficult to work around the concurrency issues (it isn't), but rather that there are several unresolved bugs - even in SQL Server 2012 still - involving this operation. [I point over a dozen of them out in this post that talks about yet another `MERGE` bug that has been fixed recently](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug). I also [go into more detail in a cautionary tip posted here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/tip-on-using-caution-with-merge/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and several others chime in [here](https://sqlblog.org/merge).

As I suggested in a comment, I don't want to sound the alarms that the sky is falling, but I'm really not all that interested in switching to `MERGE` until there are far fewer active bugs. So I would recommend sticking with an old-fashioned `UPSERT` for now, even though the actual syntax you're using might not be the source of the performance problem you're having anyway.

```
UPDATE dest SET column1 = src.column1
  FROM dbo.DestinationTable AS dest
  INNER JOIN (some join) AS src
  ON (some condition);

INSERT dest(...) SELECT cols
  FROM (some join) AS src
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.DestinationTable
    WHERE key = src.key
  );
```

For the performance issue, you'll want to look into your session's waits ([Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer)* can help with that, by firing up an Extended Events session for you), or at the very least, `blocking_session_id` and `wait_type_desc` in `sys.dm_exec_requests` while the query is running.

<sup>*Disclaimer: I used to work for SQL Sentry.</sup>