# Updating SCD2 with MERGE statement

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-merge, scd2

I want to update the SCD-2 table using `MERGE` statement.
So I have:

```
MERGE TARGET as t
USING SOURCE as s 
ON s.KEY = t.KEY
```

*Case 1:*

```
WHEN MATCHED and s.CHECKSUM <> t.CHECKSUM
```

In this case I want **first** `UPDATE` row in TARGET `set row_actual_to = getdate()`
**AND** **second** `INSERT` row from SOURCE into TARGET

*Case 2:*

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED
```

Just `INSERT` new row

**How to do that in one statement?**

Listing both `UPDATE` and `INSERT` in *Case 1* results in error : ***A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).***

Comment: The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) demonstrate exactly how to do that... so you may just have a simple syntax error - which we can't help you with without seeing your complete statement.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use merge statement. Merge statement has a long list of "won't fix" bug that can corrupt your data under certain circumstance.

Using an Update statement then an insert statement is simplier, easier to debug and will perform better then a merge stagement

[Performance issue in merge statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341831/performance-issue-in-merge-statement)

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2009/01/31/upsert-race-condition-with-merge/

https://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug